# Does Matthew 10:15 refer to different degrees of torment/punishment in the eternal judgement?

Tags: matthew, jesus, eschatology, death

Matthew 10:14-15

> [14]Whoever does not receive you, nor heed your words, as you go out of that house or that city, shake the dust off your feet.
>   [15]Truly I say to you, it will be more tolerable for the land of Sodom and Gomorrah in the day of judgment than for that city.

Does this actual mean that those who have refused and rejected the gospel their judgement will be far worse than that which was inflicted on Sodom and Gomorrah.

So does this imply varying degrees of punishment for everyone?

Comment: As the verses you cited show, the passage is related to the last days of Judaism, not the future. The judgment on the Jews, the Temple and Jerusalem occurred in 70AD.  [Mat 10:5 KJV] 5 These twelve Jesus sent forth, and commanded them, saying, Go not into the way of the Gentiles, and into [any] city of the Samaritans enter ye not:

Comment: Like other Scriptures, it can have a double referent, 70AD, and the end of time itself. Scripture both affirms that Christ is 'near' and that we should not think he's nearer than when the Antichrist comes and the end of the world is.

Comment: Cf. also "called spiritually, 'Sodom' and 'Egypt,' where also their Lord was killed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'A lake of fire', Revelation 21:8, into which the punished are cast, seems to be a universal punishment, to me. The degree of 'tolerability', spoken by Jesus in regard to the rejection of the gospel (outwardly) seems only to apply to the actual day when the punishment is revealed.

Some will assume already (as many do) that their works will, without doubt, earn them eternal hell fire. They openly reject the gospel and they accept their chosen fate.

But some assume they have earned a right to eternal bliss. They trust in their own works and they (also) reject the gospel. And these will meet with an unexpected pronouncement in the Day of Judgement.

Thus, I would say that the degree of 'tolerability' is a matter only of that particular day, when the unexpected judgement is uttered.

Thereafter, the 'lake of fire which burns with brimstone' will be a common experience, the brimstone (sulphur) causing internal burning as it is inhaled (in a resurrected body) and the fire burning externally.

Comment: Twice you said, 'seems' and once, "I would say', so basically most of this answer is  guessing.

Comment: @user48152 'Seems to me' and 'I would say' is a means of communicating what has been revealed to myself (through scripture) to other persons. No, I do not guess. I have no need to 'guess' : it is all there on the page of scripture (for them that have eyes to see it).

Comment: Hmm, officially, that's called *opinion* on BH - as you have often pointed out :)

Comment: @user48152 I refer you to the above and I have no further comment.

Answer (score 3):

**Does Matthew 10:15 refer to different degrees of torment/punishment in the eternal judgement?**

No. The penalty of sin is death - there is no *degree* within death.

**What is the Day of Judgement?**
The Day of Judgement does not result in death, torture or hell (whatever that is). Judgement is a pronouncement of guilt or innocence. It is not an execution of penalty.

The scriptures are clear that all will be judged - indeed, all are already guilty because of the inherited guilt from Adam and their own sins, thus there are no innocent except those in Christ. Only in Christ are any saved - in him guilt is removed and righteousness obtained. (any who thought they lived *good lives* and did *good things* will be made aware of that fallacious reasoning and shown the true nature that has separated them from God and true life - by no good works will any be saved)

> It is because of Him (God) that you are in Christ Jesus, **who has become for us** wisdom from God: our righteousness, holiness, and redemption. 1 Cor 1:30

> This is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, **who wants all people to be saved** and to come to the knowledge of the truth. For there is one God, and one mediator also between God and mankind, the man Christ Jesus, **who gave himself as a ransom for all**. . . 1 Tim 2:3-6

Notice this passage is referring to the presently *unsaved* - 'all people', 'mankind', 'ransom for all'. God's plan is to have Jesus (the ransom) as the mediator between Him and them. Why, so He can then torture them all forever?

How can one be counted in Christ? Only by knowing *who* Jesus is and understanding *what* Jesus' life and death (and life again) has accomplished.
One can *only* grasp this spiritual reality by spiritual means - not from the spirit of the world, but God alone - who desires all men saved.

> But God has revealed it to us by the spirit. The spirit searches all things, even the deep things of God. 1 Cor 2:10

It is from this unique vantage that salvation is offered to all - the truth about God and His son. No part of this world's system offers this true understanding - it comes only from God. Each will have opportunity to make their own, informed, rational, conscious, undeceived choice.

**Judgement is part of salvation**

Clearly, only a fraction of mankind has *had* this opportunity. Is God willing that the little village that was never reached by the 'flat-tyred-missionary', miss out on their chance, their choice? What an absurd concept - all constructed from a skewed understanding of the bible as we'll see.

Each and every life is made in God's image and each is precious to God - who desires all be saved. At the very least - that they all be given a proper choice! The bizarre rationale that man has 'freewill' while under the deception of the great deceiver is without merit. This is not freewill, it is merely the *illusion of freewill*.

This is why the deceiver is removed from the world during the Millennium. This time of renewing the earth and readying it for the second resurrection of all who ever lived and died, is done by the remnant of the world led by Christ and his transformed-to-spirit-life saints. (This is NOT the 'new heavens and earth' spoken of in Rev 21)

> an angel. . . seized the dragon, the ancient serpent, who is the devil and Satan, and **bound him for a thousand years**. And he cast him into the abyss, and shut and sealed it over him, so that he should not deceive the nations any longer Rev 20:2-

Notice in Rev 20 the "1000 years" is mentioned 6 times in 7 verses! This is not a figurative expression meant to be interpreted anyway we might imagine. There is a clear sequence revealed.

Notice - 'not deceive the nations'. So there are still nations of physical mortal people who have survived the tribulation and are present at Christ's return. Those who survived the end of this age will be able to understand and choose God unhindered by millennia of untruth and mystery. 1Tim 2 again

Their new reality living under Christ's reign of truth will be contrasted with the memory of living under the reign of evil and terror they endured under the curse of sin and the dreadful consequences of that self-centred way of life and their choices. *Only now*, can they make an informed choice and decision - only now - in Satan's absence, do they have true freewill in order to make such a decision and choose life and not death.

**History repeats**

> I call heaven and earth to witness against you today, that I have set before you life and death, blessing and curse. Therefore choose life, that you and your offspring may live. Deut 30:19

The Israelites here were God's chosen people - they had a *measure of freewill* only and were generally without God's spirit. Today, true Christians are able to exercise freewill and choose God's way of life, empowered by the indwelling Lord Jesus via the spirit - this the Israelites never had. But this is only made possible by God's express intervention to *call* each one to Himself - He always makes the first move. We never will, and cannot, know him unless He makes Himself known.

Israel was a trial run of sorts. A physical people from one Abraham who had a chance at great life in this world. To be God's people, His model nation. The future is not governed by a covenant of sin and death, of sacrifices and  laws and human priests. The new covenant is about life, spirit, grace and one sacrifice of holy blood and an eternal High Priest.

This is what will happen in the Day of Judgement.

- people will be set free from deception.
- they will encounter Jesus and his saints (Abraham, David and whoever else is raised to immortal life in the First Resurrection).
- they will be made aware of their guilt - both inherited and earned.
- they will be pronounced guilty, and as Adam was told, the penalty is death.
- they will be offered a choice to repent of that old way and choose a new way - just as it is today, it will not be by works, but grace and by the person of Jesus.

> But I tell you that men will give an account on the day of judgment for every careless word they have spoken. 37For by your words you will be acquitted, and by your words you will be condemned.” Matt 12:36-37

The words of each, like works, are another expression of faith - either in God, or in the world's ruler. *Our* words (and works) are a sign of where our worship has been directed.

> Everyone to whom much was given, of him much will be required, and from him to whom they entrusted much, they will demand the more. Luke 12:48

This is why it will be 'more tolerable' for those who are *not expected* to know right from wrong (gentiles for eg.), as much as those who were and did not choose it - *effectively rejecting it*, and God who offered it.

> So speak and so act as being about to be judged by the Law of freedom. For judgment without mercy will be to the one not having shown mercy. Mercy triumphs over judgment. James 2:12

**We see the emphasis moving from the law of sin and death to the law of spirit and life - a law of freedom.** This was not possible before Christ's redeeming sacrifice. God does not want to kill, but to save. Killing is a last resort for those unrepentant - not for those without their chance, their choice.

> For if God did not spare the angels when they sinned, but cast them deep into hell, placing them in chains of darkness to be held for judgment. . .  9if all this is so, then the Lord knows how to rescue the godly from trials and **to hold the unrighteous for punishment on the day of judgment**. 2 Pet 2:4-

Notice even here, 'hold the unrighteous for punishment' is not explicitly providing the punishment, they are held to account in a new environment of grace and freedom - only IF they are willing, now with their hinderances of deception removed, to embrace the forgiveness offered. Whatever the pending punishment is, it is not yet a fiery death. These are the 'nations' mentioned earlier.

> 2Now it will come about that in the last days, the mountain of the house of the LORD Will be established as the chief of the mountains, and will be raised above the hills; and **all the nations will stream to it**. 3 and many peoples will come and say, “Come, let’s go up to the mountain of the LORD, to the house of the God of Jacob; so that He may teach us about His ways Isaiah 2 Micah 4

During this Millennium, people will live and die - just as they do now, having children and enjoying life in a restored and healed world, both physically and spiritually.

**At the end of the 1000 years comes the Final Judgement**.

> And when the thousand years shall have been completed, Satan will be released out of his prison, and will go out to deceive the nations in the four corners of the earth Rev 20:7

This is when all who have lived, incl. those who died of old age during the Millennium, will live again and be judged just as in the first Judgement. The devil will be released and people will have their choice. If they choose evil, they will be eliminated permanently. (more on how this will work later)

Prior to the new heavens and new earth, all physical life will be finished Rev 21, Is 65. It seems there will be some who have not chosen True life and these will cease to exist. This number would be small compared to all who have ever lived.

The Judgement then is an opportunity, not for some bizarre ongoing punishment and torture, but for redemption and salvation through grace and mercy - offered in the name and person of Jesus the Christ. It is not unconditional - it IS conditional - on accepting Jesus' sacrifice and choosing the life God offers.

**How then will it be more tolerable for Sodom and Gomorrah?**

Part of the judgement will be a calling to account of all wrong done. For those who were presented the truth of Jesus with a *degree of awareness* of who he was (Capernaum Matt 11:23) (signs, miracles etc), they will be chastised for not believing. The others who were just guilty of sin from living under deception, they will be given a more gentle chastisement. However the penalty earned will be the same - death. And the offer of grace will also be the same. The sacrifice of Jesus has covered all - all are unworthy to stand alone. Being called to account when you should have known better, will be tougher (less tolerable) than those who did not know any better and sinned in ignorance.

**God's Salvation**

God called Saul (Paul) to follow His lead, just as He did Moses and David and all the others who lived their life under God's direction. He didn't call Judas to Himself, He didn't call Pharaoh - these were living under the rules of evil - the way of the world and God had a job for them to accomplish in this age. They provided 'resistance' to the right way, God's way. How could Joseph ever learn to follow God's will for him if it was easy? Jesus too endured harsh suffering so he too could learn obedience.

Are they any less precious to God than David, Paul or Abraham ? No. God's plan includes all who have ever lived and all will be offered the same salvation found in Christ - just at different times. Who are we to question how God does this or when He does it? He desires all men saved. Will they be? I think not, but all will have their opportunity. Clearly this extends to Muslims, Hindus and Jews and all the other religions who have not recognised Jesus as the name of salvation. We know even the Jews were hindered from understanding and believing.

> For if glory was in the ministry of condemnation, **much more does the ministry of righteousness abound in glory!** . . . Therefore having such a hope, we use great boldness, and not as Moses would put a veil over his face for the sons of Israel not to look intently into the end of that fading away.

> But **their minds were hardened**; for until the present day, the same veil remains at the reading of the old covenant, not being lifted, which is being removed in Christ. But unto this day, when Moses shall be read, a veil lies over their heart. **But whenever one shall have turned to the Lord, the veil is taken away**. 2 Cor 3:9-16

Anyone who cannot accept Christ still has a hard heart - no matter when they lived, God will see that they get their day of choosing and be relieved of their *inability* to choose Jesus. Their day of judgement is just the beginning of being offered that choice. This is not a *second chance* as some protest.

> For the Lord disciplines whom He loves, and He scourges every son whom He receives. Heb 12:6

> Blessed is the man You discipline, O LORD, and teach from Your law Psalm 94:12

> And they glorified God, saying, “Then to the Gentiles also God has granted repentance that leads to life.” Acts 1:18

Who are the gentiles? The opposite of His people - they had no law, no Godly principles, riddled with all kinds of sin, idolatry etc. Yet He had a place for them in His plan - even *holding back* the Jews for a time so they might be joined together as all people in Christ.

> more tolerable for the land of Sodom and Gomorrah...

The wicked, the sinners of the world - are they any different? They don't deserve a chance at true life according to the 'hellfire and torture' preachers. God says different! He desires all men saved - therefore, all will have ample, fair and just opportunity.

**What about the 'eternal punishment' construct.**

> And these will go away into eternal punishment; but the righteous into eternal life. Matt 25:46

Death is not some kind of eternal life in torture. I wont bother citing all the scripture that bears this truth. The soul that sins will die... etc.

> For the wages of sin is *death*, but the gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord. Rom 6:23

Does,

- God grant immortality to the 'wicked' so they can be punished forever?
- God's gift of life seem redundant if we are *already* immortal souls?
- Death anywhere get described as ever-living?

> For if, by the trespass of the one man, death reigned through that one man, how much more will those who receive **an abundance of grace** and of the gift of righteousness reign in life through the one man, Jesus Christ! Rom 5:17

Those *in Christ* are forgiven and declared righteous - they need no punishment.
The wicked are brought before the Judgement seat and given the *correction* necessary to move ahead and leave the past behind. We even call our prisons *Correctional Facilities*. They are intended to redeem criminal hearts and minds, restoring them to function in society as contributors not takers - granting them an opportunity for a repentance of sorts. This is the ideal on an earthly level - God is *much better* at redemption and restoration on a heavenly, spiritual level.

> Sodom and Gomorrah and the cities around them, having indulged in sexual immorality and having gone after strange flesh, in like manner with them are set forth as an example, undergoing the penalty of **eternal fire**. Jude 1:7

Are they still burning? No. Same Gr. word αἰωνίου aiōniou as Matt 25:46. This can readily be translated as 'age-long'. It is for a time. Eternal or everlasting is not required, but enforced on the text to maintain the *hell for sinners* construct. The 'age of fire' for Sodom has passed, the treatment God sentenced has been completed. They were an *example* to all who followed 2 Peter 2:6.

> And these will go away into (not 'eternal' but) 'age-long correction or discipline' ... Matt 25:46

God is a God of salvation - not destruction. He is Saviour before He is Destroyer. He is love, not of spite and cruelty.

God has planned a way that all will have opportunity to choose life - not multiple times - just once is enough. His grace and love and mercy is greater than evil and He will not allow evil to triumph because He is capricious - sending some into life and others to death because of a 'flat tyre' or deception not of their own making. The devil is the one God holds responsible and he will bear his sentence. But God holds a *greater responsibility* to all He has created  - to give them a fair chance against the evil He wrote into His plan for man to produce a better eternal outcome than otherwise possible - that's why there were two trees in the Garden and a serpent who offered an alternative.

> And when the Son of Man comes in His glory, and all the angels with Him, then he will sit upon his throne of glory. 32And **all the nations will be gathered before him**, and he will separate them one from another, as the shepherd separates the sheep from the goats. 33And indeed he will set the sheep on his right hand, and the goats on his left. Matt 25:31-

The unrighteous will have their day in court. They, even some who thought they were *safe*, will be bitterly disappointed. Are they put to death in eternal fire? No, read on.

We can get misled by the 'eternal fire' - God uses fire to cleanse - it is not a literal fire^, but a severe trial and discipline to bring about change and repentance - just as He does when He calls any to Himself. God is a [consuming fire](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63842/what-does-our-god-is-a-consuming-fire-mean-in-hebrews-1229?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C87.1404). Is He consuming His beloved creation? Or the evil that has caused it so much grief? He is a God who grants repentance, who sent His only son to die for all - He so loved the *world* and all therein.

> Now if anyone builds on the foundation with gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, or straw, 13 each one’s work will become evident; for the day will show it because it is to be revealed with fire, and the *fire itself will test the quality of each one’s work*. 14 If anyone’s work which he has built on it remains, he will receive a reward. 15 If anyone’s work is burned up, he will suffer loss; but *he himself will be saved, yet only so as through fire*. 1Cor 3:12

> And the devil, the one deceiving them, was cast into the lake of fire and of sulphur, where the beast and the false prophet also are; and they will be tormented day and night to the ages of the ages. Rev 20:10

Here the beast and FP are given their dues. The Devil, an archangel, a spirit... what is fire going to do to him? We must be careful to correctly recognise the literal and the symbolic language and to seek out the actual meaning - not just accept the default one thrust upon us.

There must be a second resurrection because there is a second death. We cannot have a second death w/o a second resurrection as the second death has no power over those in the First Res. So after the 1000 years, all others will rise to their judgement. Satan is released and they get to have their choice. Both sides will be represented - they have freewill at last to see and choose God or not. After this is the second death and permanent removal of all unrepentant flesh. Then, the new heavens and new earth is imminent.

This is a 'thumbnail sketch' only. There is much more to unpack, but the point has been to show another, more biblical reading of how the end of the age will unfold. The scriptures have often been presented with a bias not of God or His word, and all kinds of resultant bad theologies have arisen.

For those who recognise the Jewish/Israelite Holy day sequence God ordained for His people, there is a plan of salvation outlined throughout - culminating in the Feast of Tabernacles and the Last Great Day. While these are not *required* for salvation, they still exactly represent the plan God has put in place. He has allowed His people to glimpse and celebrate year after year, as the promises get closer to fulfilment, His steady, inalterable focus on redeeming His creation will become apparent.

Comment: @steveown Amen agree to that. I believe that the soul will be destroyed in the lake of fire [Matt 10:28] for those that did not repent  but some will be made eternal before for being thrown into the fire, that's the greater damnation [Matt 23:14].

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to see some of the answers here.  Yes, there are different degrees of punishment.  Not all will experience the same degree of punishment, because not all have been equally evil.  There are degrees of guilt with God, just as with man, even though God hates even the smallest of sins.

For example, it might be a sin not to stop and offer to help someone you see who needs help.  This is a sin of omission--not doing the good that you know you should do.

> Therefore to him that knoweth to do good, and doeth it not, to him it
> is sin. (James 4:17, KJV)

But what about the person who rapes and murders a 12-year-old child?  Is the rapist's sin to receive the very same punishment as the one who simply neglected to do something good?

An example of a man in the Bible who was a good man but who may not be in heaven because of his failure to discipline his sons is Priest Eli.  His neglect of training his own sons, of rebuking them when their evil deeds were known to the community, may have cost him his own salvation (we cannot be sure, but this is alluded to in the messages Eli received from God).  Consider the following texts:

> And there came a man of God unto Eli, and said unto him, Thus saith
> the LORD, Did I plainly appear unto the house of thy father, when they
> were in Egypt in Pharaoh's house? ... Wherefore kick ye at my
> sacrifice and at mine offering, which I have commanded in my
> habitation; and honorest thy sons above me, to make yourselves fat
> with the chiefest of all the offerings of Israel my people? ... And
> thou shalt see an enemy in my habitation, in all the wealth which God
> shall give Israel: and there shall not be an old man in thine house
> for ever. (1 Samuel 2:27,29,32, KJV)
>
> In that day I will perform against Eli all things which I have spoken
> concerning his house: when I begin, I will also make an end. ...
> And therefore I have sworn unto the house of Eli, that the iniquity of
> Eli's house shall not be purged with sacrifice nor offering for ever.
> (1 Samuel 3:12,14, KJV)

Those are strong words against Eli and his household.  But, supposing that Eli is lost, and Satan--who caused all the full sum of sin, woe, and suffering upon this planet--is also lost, would it be fair for each of them to receive the *exact same punishment?*

I think it is fair to say that most would agree this would be unfair.  But God is a just Judge.  He doesn't give one punishment to one who just barely missed out on Heaven, and then the same degree of punishment to the Deceiver in Chief (Satan) who caused the ruin of billions of people in addition to angels.

As the Bible says, God will reward each one *according to* what they have done.

> For the Son of man shall come in the glory of his Father with his
> angels; and then he shall reward every man according to his works.
> (Matthew 16:27, KJV)
>
> Reward her even as she rewarded you, and double unto her double
> according to her works: in the cup which she hath filled fill to her
> double. (Revelation 18:6, KJV)
>
> And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; and the books
> were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of life:
> and the dead were judged out of those things which were written in the
> books, according to their works. (Revelation 20:12, KJV)
>
> And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell
> delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every
> man according to their works. (Revelation 20:13, KJV)

It is true that all who are punished will receive eternal death, for the wages of sin is death (see Romans 6:23).  However, there will be different amounts of punishment in the flames of hell before that death comes to them.  Satan will be punished the longest, for, as the scapegoat typified in the sanctuary service, the sins of those who are forgiven are placed on him, laid to his account.  The tempter will be the one who receives the punishment for the sins he induced the saved to commit.  His punishment will be far greater than that meted out to humans.

The Bible is clear that God will punish some with a greater punishment.

> For the punishment of the iniquity of the daughter of my people is
> greater than the punishment of the sin of Sodom, that was overthrown
> as in a moment, and no hands stayed on her. (Lamentations 4:6, KJV)

Comment: I like your answer. The one point I wonder about is how *eternal* punishment could ever be either greater or lesser. That is, since there is no hope whatsoever for those lost, do degrees of punishment really matter? Since it is endless and therefore truly death *forever*, it's hard to fathom such consequences from our finite perspective.  Either way, greater or lesser, it is never ending - as though the lost really never existed at all from our glorified status in heaven. +1

Answer (score -1):

The account of Sodom and Gomorrah is in Genesis 10, 5 chapters before Abraham and the law was not given for many centuries later. So the only sin that they had on their account was Adam's transgression:

> [Rom 4:4-9 KJV] 4 Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace, but of debt. 5 But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness. 6 Even **as David also describeth the blessedness of the man, unto whom God imputeth righteousness without works, 7 [Saying], Blessed [are] they whose iniquities are forgiven, and whose sins are covered. 8 Blessed [is] the man to whom the Lord will not impute sin.** 9 [Cometh] this blessedness then upon the circumcision [only], or upon the uncircumcision also? for we say that faith was reckoned to Abraham for righteousness.

Adam was told that they would die and they did.

However, those who were under the law had a multitude of transgression counted against them:

> [Rom 5:20 KJV] 20 **Moreover the law entered, that the offence [transgression] might abound**. But where sin abounded, grace did much more abound:

So while both Jews and gentiles were sinners, only the Jews were under the Torah so unlike the gentiles they have many transgressions and each transgression carries a sanction. This is in fact why the law, though it was holy, was referred to by Paul as "the power of [Mr.] Sin":

> [1Co 15:55-56 KJV] 55 O death, where [is] thy sting? O grave, where [is] thy victory? 56  The sting of death [is] sin; and the strength of sin [is] the law.

But more importantly, Jesus was about to ratify the new covenant by his blood. In "To the Hebrews" the author points out that God will punishes those who refuse the blood of his son:

> [Heb 6:4-8 ASV] 4 For as touching those who were once enlightened and tasted of the heavenly gift, and were made partakers of the Holy Spirit, 5 and tasted the good word of God, and the powers of the age to come, 6 and [then] fell away, it is impossible to renew them again unto repentance; seeing they crucify to themselves the Son of God afresh, and put him to an open shame. 7 **For the land [Israel] which hath drunk the rain that cometh oft upon it, and bringeth forth herbs meet for them for whose sake it is also tilled, receiveth blessing from God: 8 but if it beareth thorns and thistles, it is rejected and nigh unto a curse; whose end is to be burned.**
>
> [Heb 10:26-31 KJV] 26 For if we sin wilfully after that we have received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice for sins, 27 But a certain fearful looking for of judgment and fiery indignation, which shall devour the adversaries. 28 **He that despised Moses' law died without mercy under two or three witnesses: 29 Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye, shall he be thought worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of God, and hath counted the blood of the covenant, wherewith he was sanctified, an unholy thing, and hath done despite unto the Spirit of grace?** 30 For we know him that hath said, Vengeance [belongeth] unto me, I will recompense, saith the Lord. And again, The Lord shall judge his people. 31 [It is] a fearful thing to fall into the hands of the living God.

But even that is not the end of the story because how were Sodom and Gomorrah  punished with destruction? By a quick outpouring of eternal fire:

> [Luk 17:29 KJV] 29 But the same day that Lot went out of Sodom it rained fire and brimstone from heaven, and destroyed [them] all.

Because the Jews (IE: except for the elect, Rom 9-11) rejected Christ and the new covenant, when the son of man returned in 70AD their city and their nation were destroyed in a siege by Rome:

> [Mat 24:15-22 KJV] 15 When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation [the Roman army], spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place [Jerusalem], (whoso readeth, let him understand:) 16 Then let them which be in Judaea flee into the mountains: 17 Let him which is on the housetop not come down to take any thing out of his house: 18  Neither let him which is in the field return back to take his clothes. 19 And woe unto them that are with child, and to them that give suck in those days! 20 But pray ye that your flight be not in the winter, neither on the sabbath day: 21 **For then shall be great tribulation, such as was not since the beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be. 22 And except those days should be shortened, there should no flesh be saved**: but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortened.

This was what Joel prophesied about the last days:

> [Joe 2:1-32 NLT] 1 **Sound the alarm in Jerusalem! Raise the battle cry on my holy mountain! Let everyone tremble in fear because the day of the LORD is upon us**. 2 It is a day of darkness and gloom, a day of thick clouds and deep blackness. Suddenly, like dawn spreading across the mountains, a great and mighty army appears. Nothing like it has been seen before or will ever be seen again. 3 Fire burns in front of them, and flames follow after them. Ahead of them the land lies as beautiful as the Garden of Eden. Behind them is nothing but desolation; not one thing escapes. 4 They look like horses; they charge forward like warhorses. 5 Look at them as they leap along the mountaintops. Listen to the noise they make--like the rumbling of chariots, like the roar of fire sweeping across a field of stubble, or like a mighty army moving into battle. 6 Fear grips all the people; every face grows pale with terror. 7 The attackers march like warriors and scale city walls like soldiers. Straight forward they march, never breaking rank. 8 They never jostle each other; each moves in exactly the right position. They break through defenses without missing a step. 9 They swarm over the city and run along its walls. They enter all the houses, climbing like thieves through the windows. 10 The earth quakes as they advance, and the heavens tremble. The sun and moon grow dark, and the stars no longer shine. 11 The LORD is at the head of the column. He leads them with a shout. This is his mighty army, and they follow his orders. **The day of the LORD** is an awesome, terrible thing. Who can possibly survive? 12 That is why the LORD says, "Turn to me now, while there is time. Give me your hearts. Come with fasting, weeping, and mourning. 13 Don't tear your clothing in your grief, but tear your hearts instead." Return to the LORD your God, for he is merciful and compassionate, slow to get angry and filled with unfailing love. He is eager to relent and not punish. 14 Who knows? Perhaps he will give you a reprieve, sending you a blessing instead of this curse. Perhaps you will be able to offer grain and wine to the LORD your God as before. 15 Blow the ram's horn in Jerusalem! Announce a time of fasting; call the people together for a solemn meeting. 16 Gather all the people--the elders, the children, and even the babies. Call the bridegroom from his quarters and the bride from her private room. 17 Let the priests, who minister in the LORD's presence, **stand and weep between the entry room to the Temple and the altar. Let them pray, "Spare your people, LORD!** Don't let your special possession become an object of mockery. Don't let them become a joke for unbelieving foreigners who say, 'Has the God of Israel left them?'" 18 Then the LORD will pity his people and jealously guard the honor of his land. 19 The LORD will reply, "Look! I am sending you grain and new wine and olive oil, enough to satisfy your needs. You will no longer be an object of mockery among the surrounding nations. 20 I will drive away these armies from the north. I will send them into the parched wastelands. Those in the front will be driven into the Dead Sea, and those at the rear into the Mediterranean. The stench of their rotting bodies will rise over the land." Surely the LORD has done great things! 21 Don't be afraid, my people. Be glad now and rejoice, for the LORD has done great things. 22 Don't be afraid, you animals of the field, for the wilderness pastures will soon be green. The trees will again be filled with fruit; fig trees and grapevines will be loaded down once more. 23 Rejoice, you people of Jerusalem! Rejoice in the LORD your God! For the rain he sends demonstrates his faithfulness. Once more the autumn rains will come, as well as the rains of spring. 24 The threshing floors will again be piled high with grain, and the presses will overflow with new wine and olive oil. 25 The LORD says, "I will give you back what you lost to the swarming locusts, the hopping locusts, the stripping locusts, and the cutting locusts. It was I who sent this great destroying army against you. 26 Once again you will have all the food you want, and you will praise the LORD your God, who does these miracles for you. Never again will my people be disgraced. 27 Then you will know that I am among my people Israel, that I am the LORD your God, and there is no other. Never again will my people be disgraced. 28 "Then, after doing all those things, I will pour out my Spirit upon all people. Your sons and daughters will prophesy. Your old men will dream dreams, and your young men will see visions. 29 In those days I will pour out my Spirit even on servants--men and women alike. 30 And I will cause wonders in the heavens and on the earth--blood and fire and columns of smoke. 31 The sun will become dark, and the moon will turn blood red before **that great and terrible day of the LORD arrives**. 32 But everyone who calls on the name of the LORD will be saved, for **some on Mount Zion in Jerusalem will escape, just as the LORD has said. These will be among the survivors whom the LORD has called.**
>
> [Rev 11:8 KJV] 8 And their dead bodies [shall lie] in the street of the great city, which spiritually is called Sodom and Egypt, where also our Lord was crucified.

Comment: I am obviously stupid because I cannot see how this has anything to do with the question.

Comment: Update: The reason that my answer doesn't appear to answer the question is that Nigel edited the question after (possibly in response to) my answer. Peace.

Comment: Ok well sorry then, it answers the question. I had not refreshed my screen and it said it had been edited just a few minutes at 27 minutes ago

Comment: My answer was edited three times. But the question by collen ndhlovu has never been edited.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the wrong date, sorry.