# What does "our God is a consuming fire " mean in Hebrews 12:29?

Tags: hebrews

Hebrews 12:29 "for our God is a consuming fire".  ESV

1, How does the consuming fire of Hebrews 12:29 compare with the fire that does not consume in Exodus 3:2 "but the bush was not consumed"?

2, Does "our God is a consuming fire" in any way suggest that there will be a time when all that it consumes will have been consumed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And His voice shook the earth then, but now He has promised, saying, “YET ONCE MORE I WILL SHAKE NOT ONLY THE EARTH, BUT ALSO THE HEAVEN.” 27This expression, “Yet once more,” denotes **the removing of those things which can be shaken**, as of created things, so that those things which cannot be shaken may remain. 28Therefore, since **we receive a kingdom which cannot be shaken**, let’s show gratitude, by which we may offer to God an acceptable service with reverence and awe; 29for our God is a consuming fire. Heb 12:26- NASB

The context of Hebrews 12 lends no correlation to the burning bush.

It does express a contrast between the OC and the New Covenant. The new will eventually consist of only spirit and no flesh - no more corruption, and no more sin. All that remains of a physical age will be removed along with every trace of the evil and darkness that filled and soiled it to the core.

God as 'a consuming fire' has a plan to cleanse the earth and even the memories of it. We will have a new earth - it's still an earth, just a new earth.

> For behold, I will create new heavens and a new earth. The former things will not be remembered, nor will they come to mind. Is 65:17

Nothing will be left that is not supposed to be left. Nothing will survive the intense fury and heat of God's wrath on evil and its residue.

> But the day of the Lord will come like a thief, in which the heavens will pass away with a roar and the elements will be destroyed with intense heat, and the earth and its works will be discovered (or burnt up). 2 Pet 3:10 NASB

Answer (score 2):

Hebrews 12:29

> for our **God** is a consuming **fire**

Exodus 3:2

> There the **angel** of the Lord appeared to him in flames of **fire** from within a bush. Moses saw that though the bush was on fire it **did not burn up**.

How does the consuming fire of Hebrews 12:29 compare with the fire that does not consume in Exodus 3:2 "but the bush was not consumed"?

It serves as a contrast and not as a foil. The burning bush was the angel of the Lord. It was a sign to convince Moses personally.

On the other hand, the consuming fire motif is completely different.
Hebrews 12:29 correlates with Deuteronomy 9:3

> But understand that today the LORD your **God** goes across ahead of you as a **consuming fire**; He will destroy them and subdue them before you. And you will drive them out and **annihilate** them swiftly, as the LORD has promised you.

Does "our God is a consuming fire" in any way suggest that there will be a time when all that it consumes will have been consumed?

Yes, that's the promise as illustrated in Deuteronomy.

Comment: As long as evil is evil will not there be a reason for "And their fire is not quenched"? Isaiah 6:24.

Comment: That depends on your definitions of "consumed", "quenched", and "time".